# Prove that $40\mid 3^{4N}-1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $40 \mid 3^{4N}-1$ for all integers $N$.

How would I prove this by using modular arithmetic?

I can't remember how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

$3^4=81\equiv 1$ (mod $40$), hence $3^{4N}=(3^4)^N\equiv 1$ (mod $40$) for all $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide ${3^4}=81$ by 40 the remainder will be 1 and if you divide

${81^N}$ by 40 it will give the remainder ${1^N}=1$.Hence if you divide

${81^N}-1$ by 40 it will givethe remainder $1-1=0$.

So $40|{81^N}-1{\implies}\;40|{3^{4N}}-1$ for any natural number N.